# Returning char[] value in C

Tags: c, c-strings

I m trying to understand how to return a string in c. I tried different ways but didnt manage to do it. Could you edit this code?

```
char dublicate(char str[])
{
    return str[20];
}

int main()
{
    char str[20];
    scanf("%s", &str);
    printf("%s", dublicate(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a very basic question, please read a C tutorial walkthrough. You need to allocate memory and return it to make the variable persistent,

Comment: Strings in C are tough to get at first.  You need to work through a tutorial, slowly

Comment: It is not possible to return a string in C, nor to pass one as a parameter.

Comment: Also learn respecting and understanding the compiler's warning(s) and fixing the code accordingly.

Comment: Assuming POSIX, the easiest way to duplicate a C-"string" is to use `strdup()`. Mind to `free()` the result if not needed any more.

Comment: With strings in C, you have to understand pointers and dynamic memory to use them effectively. Until you have those down pat, it will be harder to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. `string_dupe` creates a copy of the string sent from `scanf`, which must use `malloc()` or `strdup()` to allocate space for it on the heap. The pointer to the first element in `duplicate` is then returned to main and printed out. Then `free()` is executed to release the memory allocated for the string on the heap.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 20

char *string_dupe(char *string);

int
main(void) {
    char str[SIZE];
    char *strcopy = NULL;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    strcopy = string_dupe(str);

    printf("\nYour copied string: %s", strcopy);

    free(strcopy);

    return 0;
}

char 
*string_dupe(char *string) {
    char *duplicate = NULL;

    if ((duplicate = malloc(strlen(string)+1)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory not allocated\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy(duplicate, string);

    return duplicate;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the return type of `dublicate`, and change how you read into `str` in your call to `scanf`:

```
char *dublicate(char str[])
{
    return str;
}

int main() {
    char str[20];
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%s", dublicate(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP is probably trying to duplicate the string.

Comment: True. OP: you can use the `strdup()` library function instead of writing your own `dublicate()`.

Answer (score -2):

A string is essentially a pointer to a character that is the first character of the string. (The end of the string is determined by the '\0' character.) So all you have to return is a char pointer.

Comment: "*A string is essentially a pointer to a character  ...*" No, a "string" in C is a `char`-array with at least one element being equal to `'\0'`.

Comment: Depends on how you define 'array'. You can create a string without having an actual array-variable. In the end, there has to be an array of chars somewhere, but it doesnt necessarily have to involve a `char[]`